# Microsoft SQL Server column size

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

If for example I have a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(100)` column.

If I insert a string of size 50, will it be the same size whether it's `100` or `MAX` in both columns?

If yes does this apply to all types such as `VARBINARY`?

Comment: `CHAR(100)` will always store 100 characters. `VARCHAR(100)` will only store as many characters as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will not change sizes when you insert it to the database. It will not take **all** the space you allow it to take.

Comment: SQL Server won't reserve any extra space in the data/index pages based on column length just in case it becomes bigger.